# Docker for windows: Bind mounting an Azure SMB drive fail

Tags: windows, azure, docker, share, smb

I spent days on this issue, can't figure out how it's done?
Mounting the drive letter from Azure file share works fine using

```
New-PSDrive -Name T -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\xxxx.file.core.windows.net\share" -Scope Global -Persist
```

The drive can be accessed in both PowerShell and in explorer, even after windows reboot.

But when trying to mount that in a container fail to say the path does not exist.

```
docker run -d --name webserver1 -v T:\:c:\share -p 80:80 microsoft/iis


Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'T:\:c:\share': invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: t:\.
```

I also tried to add the SMB drive via

```
New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath "\\xxxx.file.core.windows.net\share" -Credential $credentialObject -LocalPath T: -FullAccess @( "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" ) -Persistent $true -RequirePrivacy $true
```

Then I can bind mount T: but get "access was denied" instead when trying to check c:\share inside the container. What am I doing wrong? Also referring to this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37863

If there is another way to mount the SMB share directly into the container without first mounting it in windows, that would be fine too. I solved it with Linux but doesn't seem to be possible in windows.